# laravel not rendering js components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

the same questions already asked here but answer do not resolve my problem

[1. Laravel: vue components not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002386/laravel-vue-components-not-rendering)

[2. Vue component not showing in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971106/vue-component-not-showing-in-laravel)

this my home.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Full stack blog</title>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="app">
        <mainapp></mainapp>   #this one show as read
        </div>
    </body>

<script src="{{mix('/js/app.js')}}"></script>
</html>
```

this is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue')

Vue.component('mainapp',require('./components.vue/mainapp.vue').default)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

and this my mainapp.vue

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <h1>this is the frist components</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

and
laravel : 8
Vue: 2.6.12

when I run `npm run watch` and `php artisan serve`

then I check in 127.0.0.1/8000

I can see this

> You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to turn on
> production mode when deploying for production. See more tips at
> https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

but it does not render   how can I solve this?

Comment: is this a typo??  `</mainapp>` should be `<mainapp />`

Comment: < mainapp> added sorry i edit question